# ThreeJS Collada Model not Showing up

Tags: render, webgl, three.js, collada

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my Collada export will not show up.

running

http://threejsexperiment.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

github

https://github.com/markbreneman/TroubleShooting/tree/master/ThreeJSCollada

If i take a look at the Collada example(http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html)

and swap my model for the monster everything shows up fine, so I know it's not a problem with the model. I feel like it's an issue with the way I'm calling the loader but I'm lost as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `group.add(THEMIS)` inside the `loader.load()` callback.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm.  To be honest though I'm still a little lost on why it has to be added within the loader callback, because the object would still show up in the console when it was outside it just wouldn't render. If you have a second to explain I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Because the callback was being executed after the `group.add(THEMIS)`. You were basically adding it to the group when THEMIS was still `undefined`.